# Change @prmMax from asp.net into SQL-server Query?

Tags: sql-server

(Editor's note, I have attempted to translate and format more appropriately. See below for the original)

I want to make an SQL query to get those "ACTIVATED WITHIN 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION" and those "ACTIVATED ABOVE 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION". How can I fix this query?

Below this query is for GET THOSE "ACTIVATED WITHIN 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION"

```
 select Month(reg_Date) as RegMonth, datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) as RegDiff,
 count(*) as RegCount from dailyregistration
 where datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) <= @prmMax
 group by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
 order by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
 Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
 Must declare the scalar variable "@prmMax".
```

How can I fix it?

Here is an example row in the DB: (slightly unintelligible)

```
 #month##Register#        #activation elapsed time#                 #Activated##Unactivated##port out#
             #<0##0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##14##21##28##>28    
 #March##1360#
```

Original Below

---

**I HAD TO MAKE IT INTO SQL-SERVER QUERY FORM
TO GET THOSE "ACTIVATED WITHIN 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION" AND ALSO "ACTIVATED ABOVE 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION". HOW CAN I CHANGE IT INTO SQL-SERVER QUERY?
BEFORE THIS I HAD TRY FOR IT IN SQL SERVER,**

**Below this query is for GET THOSE "ACTIVATED WITHIN 28 DAYS AFTER REGISTRATION"**

select Month(reg_Date) as RegMonth, datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) as RegDiff,
count(*) as RegCount from dailyregistration
where datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) <= @prmMax
group by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
order by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)

**BUT IT PROMPT OUT WITH THE ERROR** 
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@prmMax".

**HOW CAN I CHANGE IT INTO CORRECT ? SInce i had to make it as tabel** 
**Can you please copy the below data into NOTEPAD and then you will see what i need, sorry that i can't attact any picture in.**

```
  Total            Activation Elapsed Time (in Days)                                                              Total           Total     Total
```

Month Registered < 0    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   14  21  28  > 28    Activated   Unactivated Port Out
March    1360     0 571 142 56  42  28  21  22  10  76  37  15  109 1129                 231    0
April    13601    0 7577    1260    381 259 200 139 134 138 433 277 233 947 11978               1623    227
May  14216    0 6726    1397    479 333 212 187 150 180 565 332 254 1004    11819               2397    412
June     9738     0 5551    999 340 214 132 112 87  77  365 168 107 435 8587                1151    354
July     10527    0 6528    1225    342 190 130 88  94  61  293 139 86  373 9549                 978    474
August   15214    1 10115   1353    384 255 184 136 97  108 397 224 143 298 13695               1519    369
September23724    0 13499   3671    1230    893 328 329 498 226 1969    112 64  27  22846                878    204
October  8383     0 5673    1692    323 77  30  20  8   8   14  0   0   0   7845                 538    237

Comment: can you make a smaller case also give your question a real title and maybe people would help you to solve your issue

Comment: _Less_ bold type and caps will actually make your question more readable and attract more attention.  Also: we do need to see _some_ code.  Just not the entire source file.

Comment: add     
Declare @prmMax datetime
Set @prmMax = '01/01/1800' -- your date 
before the query

Comment: declare @prmMax(28)
--------------------


select Month(reg_Date) as RegMonth,
    datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) as RegDiff,
    count(*) as RegCount from dailyregistration
where
 datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) <= @prmMax
group by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
order by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)


is it declare like tat? but it's no works

Answer (score 2):

Very simple : your query is using a parameter **`@prmMax`** and you have obviously not declared that parameter - simply declare it and give it a value and all your problems are gone! I don't know if you're calling this inside a stored procedure (does the stored proc have a parameter called @prmMax?) or whatever - the variable just simply doesn't exist and that's your problem.

```
 SELECT 
    MONTH(reg_Date) as RegMonth, 
    DATEDIFF(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) as RegDiff,
    COUNT(*) as RegCount 
 FROM 
    dbo.dailyregistration
 WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) <= @prmMax
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
 GROUP BY
    MONTH(reg_Date), 
    DATEDIFF(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
 ORDER BY 
    MONTH(reg_Date), 
    DATEDIFF(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
```

Comment: Or since he only wanted 28 days just enter the number 28 although that does limit you to only ever using 28

Comment: Yes, that's a quick fix - but probably, the problem lies deeper and the OP doesn't realize he's copied&pasted code from some other place and missed to check for stuff like variables "dangling" in the air now....

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer, but only because of the OP's comment that they still can't get this to work, even after [the correct answer from marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564092/change-prmmax-from-asp-net-into-sql-server-query/1564691#1564691), where the need to declare @prmMax and initialize @prmMax is pointed out. To make the query run add the `DECLARE` and `SET` before your query, like here:

```
DECLARE @prmMax int
SET @prmMax=28

--your query here--
select Month(reg_Date) as RegMonth, datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) as RegDiff,
 count(*) as RegCount from dailyregistration
 where datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate) <= @prmMax
 group by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
 order by Month(reg_Date), datediff(day, reg_date, reg_activationdate)
```